# Why are my two different angularjs services resolving to the same restful Java EE web service?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jakarta-ee

I have two angularjs services and they are supposed to call different restful services (the first one retrieves a single user and the second one returns an array of users).  Why are they both calling the service to get array of users?

Here are the two angularjs services:

```
angular.module('clearsoftDemoApp').factory('UserDetail', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users/:id', {}, {
    find: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}},
    update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
    delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
});
```

});

```
angular.module('clearsoftDemoApp').factory('Users', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users', {}, {
    findAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
});
```

});

And here is the relevant code from the Java RESTful service:

```
@Stateless
@Path("clearsoft.demo.users")
public class UsersFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Users> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ClearsoftDemoBackendPU")
private EntityManager em;

public UsersFacadeREST() {
    super(Users.class);
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Users find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Users> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

The problem is that when i run this, both angularjs services seem to be calling the findAll() web service which is not my intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource` is meant to retrieve data from an endpoint, manipulate it and send it back and it uses a set of default parameters that can be explicitely overriden on calls.
Just the use the internal resource matching process of *AngularJS* instead defining to resouce functions, i.e. when defining only the first `UserDetails` resource and calling *`http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users`*, then you will get all users loaded.

For that you need to define the `:id` as an optional paramter.

One side note is you may need to add the `[ngResource]` module so don't forget to include it.

```js
var service = angular.module("clearsoftDemoApp", ["ngResource"]);
// UserDetail Resource
service.factory('UserDetail', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(
    '/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users/:id',
    {id: "@id" }, 
    {
      find: {method: 'GET'},
      update: { method: 'PUT'},
      delete: { method: 'DELETE'}
  });
});
```

The below snippet defines a `UserDetail` module which let you fire below calls:

```js
// Get all users
var users = UserDetail.query(); // Calls: GET /ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users

// Get user with iD 1
var user = UserDetail.get({},{'id': 1}); // Calls: GET /ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users/1

// Find user with iD 1
var user = UserDetail.find({},{'id': 1}); // Calls: GET /ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users/1
```